# Letting one symbolic function be a function of another

Tags: matlab

I have the following code

```
>> syms t
>> syms u
>> aux = @(u) 1/sqrt(8.4e-5*u^(-2) + 0.3*u^(-1) + u^2*0.7 + (1-8.4e-5 -0.3-0.7));
>> syms a
>> temp_sf = @(a) (1/70) * int(aux(u),0,a);
```

`temp_sf` is a symbolic function of `a`, which is theoretically a function of `a`. I want to plot `a` with respect to `t`, but when I use `fplot`, I get an error that the two function must be of the same variable (which makes sense). So, is there a way to tell MATLAB that `a` is a general function of `t`?

Comment: Isn't it `syms a(t)` ?